# How do I put subscripted variables as entries inside of the matrix using Latex?

Tags: matrices, subscripts

I am trying to put a subscripted variable `w_11`, `w_12`, `w_21`, and `w_22` inside of the matrix, but I am keep on having a error saying "Missing $ inserted." Is it impossible to put a subscript inside of the matrix? Followings are my code that are having errors. Thank you!

```
\begin{frame}{Calculating Inputs}

    \begin{equation}
        W = \begin{pmatrix} w$_{11}$ & w$_{21}$ \\ w$_{12}$ & w$_{22}$ \end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation}

    \newline

    \begin{equation}
        X = \begin{pmatrix} x$_1$ \\ x$_2$ \end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation}

    \newline 

    \begin{equation}
        W * X = 
        \begin{pmatrix} w$_{11}$ & w$_{21}$ \\ w$_{12}$ & w$_{22}$ \end{pmatrix} 
        \begin{pmatrix} x$_1$ \\ x$_2$ \end{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix} w$_{11}$*x$_{1}$ + w$_{21}$*x$_{2}$ \\ w$_{12}$*x$_{1}$ + w$_{22}$*x$_{2}$ \end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `\begin{equation}` already enters math-mode, so you don't have to enclose subscripts (nor anything) in `$...$`. Remove all the `$` that are in the code above and it will work.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you! That worked..haha I'm learning-!

Comment: Good to know :) You can also remove those `\newline` (you will hardly ever need to use them, actually) and remove blank lines between equations, so the spacing is right. And you can also replace the `*` by `\times`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by removing extra `$`.